# How can I manipulate the output image the computer monitor displays before it gets displayed?

Tags: monitor, gpu, framebuffer

I have been reading into GPU abstractions and framebuffers, but I have not been able to find specific literature that satisfies my needs. I would like to programmatically manipulate the image sent from the GPU to the monitor before the monitor displays the image. Essentially, I want to manipulate the pixels on the screen (rearranging them) to effectively create a distortion when one uses the computer. If possible, an OS independent solution would be preferred and I am open to any language.

Thanks,
Saif

Comment: What you're asking for would require that something sit between the GPU and your monitor that is capable of performing transformations on the data. Unless you physically put something there (like a KVM on steroids), there's nothing on that path that'd allow you to do this.

Comment: OS dependence won't be your problem - graphics card dependence will. Your graphics card's driver api is probably where you need to start. Most home-user cards probably won't let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

DLL code injection might work (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection). Or you could write a screensaver that starts with a screen-shot of the current display and then alters that image. The distortions could be done as warps using matrix transformations or other distortions.